# parse my proprietary string format

Tags: c#, string, extract

How can we get the numbers 7 and 4 and 5 from the following string:

```
MODULE potmtpMAIN main <info: "Enterprise Optimizer 7.4 for COR Technology 5.5 --    
Advanced Solver Edition", url:"http://EO.riverlogic.com", url_menu:"EO Online...",  
app_id:"EOAS",app_name:"Enterprise Optimizer AS", app_major:7,  
app_minor:4,app_micro:5,app_copyright:"\251 1996-2010 River Logic Inc.\r\nAll 
Rights Reserved.">
```

The search must be based on app_major: app_minor: and app_micro

Thank You in advance

Comment: Do you want 7, 4, 5 in that order with no repeats? Are you trying to fill an array? Do you really want a regular expression that gives you 7.4 and 5.5? Do you want the numbers in the date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple regex to pick out each part, with example code for someone unfamiliar with regular expressions in .NET: (Edited, since the original question was edited to remove the asterisks).

```
Regex Exp = new Regex(@"(?<=\W)app_major:(?'Number'\d+)");

Match M = Exp.Match(input);

if(M.Success)
{
    string Number = M.Groups["Number"].Value;
}
```

You could just use 3 different expressions, one for each part you want to pick out of the string.

Explanation:

- The first part `(?<=\W)` ensures that the match is preceded by a non-word character (in thise case, most likely a comma).
- The second part `app_major:` matches the literal part of the string you're looking for.
- `(?'Number'\d+)` is a captured group, which we label `Number`, where we're trying to match one or more digits `\d+`.

Answer (score 5):

I did it using LINQ... might not be the best way but it was fun to figure it out:

```
string test = "<info:\"Enterprise Optimizer 7.4 for COR Technology 5.5 -- Advanced Solver Edition\", url:\"http://EO.riverlogic.com\", url_menu:\"EO Online...\", app_id:\"EOAS\",app_name:\"Enterprise Optimizer AS\", **app_major:7**, **app_minor:4**,**app_micro:5**,app_copyright:\"251 1996-2010 River Logic Inc.\r\nAll Rights Reserved.\">";

var result = test.Split(',').
    Select(p => p.Trim().Split(':')).
    Where(i => i[0].Trim().StartsWith("**app_")).
    Select(r => new { Key = r[0].Trim('*'), Value = r[1].TrimEnd('*') });
```

Produces:

```
result = {{Key = "app_major", Value = "7"},
          {Key = "app_minor", Value = "4"}, 
          {Key = "app_micro", Value = "5"}}
```

It could probably even be done much more elegantly :)

**EDIT:** If you want to make it very simple to access what you want do:

```
var result = test.Split(',').
    Select(p => p.Trim().Split(':')).
    Where(i => i[0].Trim().StartsWith("**app_")).
    Select(r => new { Key = r[0].Trim('*'), Value = r[1].TrimEnd('*') }).
    ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
```

Then to get the value out just give it the key like this:

```
var version = result["app_major"] ?? "Not Found";
```

Note I have tested the LINQ solution vs the Regex solution and the LINQ version is not that much of a difference in terms of speed but it is a bit slower than the regex answers posted.  The regex answer though do not clean the data for you and present it in a easy to use manner.  The `ToDictionary` part really slows it down (in terms of real time though it is almost nothing still) but it does make the results easier to use.

Comment: If you're going to use LINQ, why not do `new []{"**app_major", "**app_minor", "**app_micro"}.Contains(i[0].Trim())` in your `Where` predicate?  Not that I agree in any way that LINQ should be used as a replacement for regular expressions...

Comment: @Michael Petito there is a ton of ways to do it I am sure and I am not saying LINQ is the right way to go either but just wanted to show that it could be done using LINQ.

Comment: +1 for something other than regular expressions. You know the saying... "now you've got 2 problems..." http://bit.ly/agDTvi

Comment: @Michael Petito changed it to be a bit more generic by just checking `StartsWith` in the `Where`. Little bit cleaner now :)

Answer (score 3):

Just do a Regex, something like `app_m....:\d` might work, but I'm not sure (I usually use one of the tools like RegexBuilder to make them).

The documentation for `Regex.Match` has a sample to show you how to write the actual code to use the regex:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx

Edit: Something like this might work:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(mystring, "app_major:\d{1-2}");
if(m.Success)
{
     string appMajor = m.Value.SubString(m.Value.IndexOf(":"));
}
```

If I remember correctly the `\d{1-2}` bit should mean that you want to get one or two digits.

Comment: So far I have this:

If (Regex.IsMatch(mystring, "app_major"))
{
 //sucess
 // I don't know what to do here to get the number that comes after "app_major"
}
else
{
 \\not found
}

Comment: @microsumol - I've updated my answer with a sample since the code looks better there than in the comment. I've not tested that code though.

Answer (score 3):

With regex `(?<=:)\d(?=\*\*)`

**Edited** : As the question is edited so is the answer.
`(?<=(app_major|app_minor|app_micro):)\d*`

Comment: Since OP edited question (presumably to get rid of a failed bold attempt) this regex should be `(?<=:)\d(?=,)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression:

```
string regex = @"app_major:(?<major>\d+).*app_minor:(?<minor>\d+).*app_micro:(?<micro>\d+";
   RegexOptions options =        
      (RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | 
      RegexOptions.Singleline | 
      RegexOptions.Multiline  | 
      RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Regex reg = new Regex(regex, options);

Match match = reg.Matches(yourString);

string major = match.Groups[1].Value
string minor = match.Groups[2].Value
string micro = match.Groups[3].Value
```

Comment: I have this `using` directive you can borrow.

Comment: haha, sorry that was the autogenerated code given to me by Regulator.  I've edited the namespace references out :)